# Creating Specific Alerts to Certain Users

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, setup

Here's the issue. Two of my co-workers need alerts for specific criteria in the CAPACI list. One of my co-workers gets alerts sent right to his email. All he knows is if someone submits a form with “Mechanical Engineering” selected from the “Responsible Department” field, he gets an email notification in outlook about it. Since I'm the new IT for this company, I'm unfamiliar with how SharePoint really works when it comes to these aspects. I have already tried setting alerts but when looking at the co-workers (who gets the emails) alerts (in all fields) he has none, yet receives emails.

Answer (score 0):

Create two views for the list, make sure they meet the requirements for each user.  For example, if User A needs all new items where 'Mechanical Engineering' is selected in the 'Responsible Department' field, then have the alert filter for those items.  Create an alert on that view for that user.

As for viewing the alerts already in place, go to Site Settings, and click on User Alerts.  Find the user in the drop down, and click the button to view the user's alerts.